# Isomorphism between a field and the quotient of affine coordinate ring by a maximal ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to know why is $A(Y)/m$ isomorphic to $k$ when $m$ is a maximal ideal and $A(Y)$ is the affine coordinate ring of a variety. It is in Hartshorne, but i didn't understood this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The quotient of a commutative ring with unit by a maximal ideal is always a field.

Comment: Yes, but it does not means that this field will be isomorphic to k. I want to know why are them isomorphic in this case.

Comment: @Joe: this is not even close to true. What is true is that any map between fields is injective, but that's all you can say. In this case, you need $k$ to be algebraically closed, and then you also need a version of the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Comment deleted.

Comment: Thanks, Qiaochu. Can you provide me a clear answer about this isomorphism and the Nullstellensatz application? thanks in advance

Comment: Let $k$ be a field and $B$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra. If $B$ is also a field, then it is a finite algebraic extension of $k$. (Atiyah-McDonald, Introduction to Commutative Algebra, Chapter V, Corollary 5.24).

Comment: @Krish that gets us almost all the way there, and then we just note that we probably assumed that $k$ is algebraically closed, so a finite algebraic extension of $k$ has to be isomorphic to $k$ itself. (I realize you were probably assuming that implicitly, but I wanted it to be explicit for @Billy.)

Comment: @Krish you should really post your answer with my added comment as an answer (as well as noting that $A(Y)$ is a finitely-generated $k$-algebra).

Comment: @TannerStrunk I didn't want to give a complete answer, that's why I just gave reference and hope that OP can draw the conclusion from here. And yes!!! One needs the assumption that $k$ is algebraically closed to conclude. As far as I can remember, this is the assumption in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Chapter I.

Comment: @Krish Yeah I'm sure that assumption is all over Hartshorne. He's not trying to be some wild mathematician dealing with a field that has nontrivial finite extensions :P

Comment: Thank you all. So the isomorphism is given by the way of the construction of an algebraic extension of k with the finitely generated k-algebras?

Comment: (And yes, I don't want to be a wild mathematician, by now I just want to understand algebraic geometry correctly :p )

Comment: @BillyBones Yes!!! Since $A(Y)/m$ is a field, which is also a finitely generated $k$-algebra (*why?*), it a finite algebraic extension of $k$. But $k$ is also algebraically closed. So it must be isomorphic to $k$.

Comment: It is a finitely generated k-algebra because $A(Y)$ is one too, so the quotient inherits the structure over k, am I right?

Comment: @BillyBones Yes!! You have got it.

Comment: Thanks, @Krish . I have answered the question below, can you review it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer then is: Since $A(Y)/m$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, because it inherits this structure from the coordinate ring $A(Y)$, we can say that there is an isomorphism from $A(Y)/m$ to $k$, because $k$ is algebraically closed and $A(Y)/m$ is a finite algebraic extension of $k$.

Comment: @Krish is this one better?

Comment: Yes!!! In the last line write "$A(Y)/m$ is a finite *algebraic* extension of $k$".